# quantmod::chartSeries does not plot all components

Tags: r, quantmod

I have read quite a lot of R docs, but I can't find anything I recognized as the answer to this. My forehead is sore from banging it against the desk. ;)

This is specific to `library(quantmod)`, because that is what I am trying to learn, but I suppose it is a general question too.

R 2.12.2 GUI 1.36 Leopard build 64-bit (5691)
Mac OS X 10.6.6

I am trying to replicate the behaviour of a `quantmod` example at http://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/

From the GUI, all is well - the below generates a chart like this http://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/AAPL-full.png:

```
> require(TTR)
> getSymbols("AAPL")
[1] "AAPL"
> chartSeries(AAPL)
> addMACD()
> addBBands()
```

But when I `source()` a .R file from the GUI, I only get the chart for

```
> chartSeries(AAPL)
```

That is, only a price chart and a volume chart underneath it. Further, if I try the following from the command line it kind of works as expected.

```
$ R --no-save `<`quantmod.R
```

A file called `Rplots.pdf` is generated, which contains three pages. The third page contains the price + volume + MACD + Bollinger Bands.

What is `quantmod` doing to make life so difficult? Or what do I not understand that is blindingly obvious and is making life so difficult?

What do I have to do to get the sourced script to be able to use the `addMACD()` and `addBBands()` functions to the chart?

As a side question, where are the data generated by `addMACD()` and `addBBands()` stored?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading through the quantmod docs and before banging your head against the desk, try searching the R-SIG-Finance mailing list archives (one way is via the "Support Lists" tab on [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org)).  This question has come up several times on the list.

To answer your main question, see the "Note" section of `?TA`:

> ```
>  Calling any of the above methods from within a function or script
>  will generally require them to be wrapped in a ‘plot’ call as they
>  rely on the context of the call to initiate the actual charting
>  addition.
> ```

So you should change the example to:

```
> require(TTR)
> getSymbols("AAPL")
[1] "AAPL"
> chartSeries(AAPL)
> plot(addMACD())
> plot(addBBands())
```

To answer your side question, see the "Value" section of `?chartSeries`, along with `help("chob-class")` and `help("chobTA-class")`.

Comment: Thanks once again Joshua. plot(addMACD()) etc. did the trick. I also found a more efficient incantation in the quantmod docs that goes something like this: chartSeries(AAPL,TA="addVol():addMACD()")

Comment: The "efficient incantation" mentioned by @BeastOfBodmin is excellent for use in a function.  However, it didn't work for me unless I used a different syntax: `chartSeries(AAPL, TA = c( addVol(), addMACD() ) )`